# Expose securely Rest API for third party application

Tags: spring-boot

We are building an enterprise software for our client. Our clients have their other application from other vendor. we have to expose API for other software.

Currently we are using Authorization code flow for our application user.

So for external software, what should be the secured way to expose API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password grant flow is the way to go. You can go for authorization code flow for more security if you want.

You can not go with Implicit grant or Client credential grant in your case.

Comment: Password grant flow, third party app request for access token with username and password with client secret . so third party application should store access token also should get new token when it expires

Comment: can we use api token for this purpose?